# Find pdf of $Z^2$ if $Z\sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, moment-generating-functions

> Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=Z^2$. Find $f_Y(y)$ by using moment generating function.

So I have moment generating function $M_Y(t)=E(e^{Z^2t})=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{z^2t}\cdot f_{Z^2}(z)dz$

Not sure how to continue from here. I believe for $Z\sim N(0,1)$ I have $f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}$

Comment: if you have calculated the MGF, you can match this with the closed form expression for the MGF of a well known distribution and then you'll know which distribution you've got. Once you know that, you get the PDF for free.

However!
To do it your way, following from where you've got to:
$f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}(\Phi(\sqrt{y})-\Phi(-\sqrt{y})) = \frac{1}{2}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}(f_Z(\sqrt{y})+f_Z(\sqrt{y}))$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Am I able to just sub in the density function of $f_Z$? I've made an edit, which I think is close but I guess I don't understand the part of taking $E(e^{Z^2t})$

Comment: yeah exactly, the $x^2$ will be an $x$ here i.e. $x^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-x/2}$. Should match a chi-squared with 1 degree of freedom

Comment: ah I see, well if you do the MGF way, $\mathbb{E}[e^{Z^2 t}]$ you do the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{z^2 t}f_Z(z)dz$. I.e. you compute it as if it is a function of the random variable $Z$. You can complete the square in the exponential and make it look like a normal PDF with an extra term multiplied (the MGF bit)

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst So if I have an expected value $E(e^{Z^nt})$ I can simply take $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{z^nt} f_Z(z^n) dz$? Is that what you mean?

Comment: The same as what you said but $f_Z(z)$. It is just like when you take the variance and this is the function $(Z-\mu)^2$ of $z$, you use the density of $Z$

Comment: You are asking questions that you can find answers to by a simple google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y)=\mathbb{P}(Z^2 \leq y)$$ with $y>0$

We have that $$F_y(y)=\mathbb{P}(Z^2 \leq y)=\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{y}\leq Z \leq \sqrt{y})=\Phi(\sqrt{y})-\Phi(-\sqrt{y})$$ where $\Phi$ is the cdf of $Z$

Differentiating $F_y$ wrt to $y$, we have $$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}f_{Z}(\sqrt{y})+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}f_{Z}(-\sqrt{y})$$

We also know that $$f_{Z}(-\sqrt{y})=f_{Z}(\sqrt{y})$$

Therefore,
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}f_{Z}(\sqrt{y})$$